# Best way to tie data to multiple users?

Tags: sql, sqlite

What's the best way to relate pieces of data to multiple users in SQLite?

Say I have a table of users, then another table with stocks they've purchased. What would be a preferred solution for multiple users to share the same data?

Example: User1 and User2 own stock in GOOG and APPL. User3 only owns GOOG, etc.

How best would I represent these relations?

Comment: I would keep a table of `stock`, which would have (indexed) columns for company and amount,, mapped to user id's (using a foreign key to the user table)

Comment: This sounds like a 'many-to-many' relationship. So use a link table (user, stock).

Comment: There is one missing piece of information in your question: Do you have a need to link between users that purchased the same stocks? If yes, what would be the purpose of this link?

Comment: @FDavidov No, there's no need to link between users. Only users to stocks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to my comment (i.e. no link between users that purchased the same stock) and since your tables (their records) are rather small and hence no specific allocation issues would be expected, I would simple have two tables, one for the users (with their ID) and one with three columns: User_ID, Stock name, and amount.

Comment: So how does this address when there are multiple users owning the same stock?

Comment: If you want to get a list of all the users that have the same stock, you simple select from the second table all the User_IDs from those records where the stock name is the one you want to get (of you need not the user_ID but the name, you can make a simple join with the users table to get the names).